# Add and Compile apt-get package manager for LFS

Tags: linux, apt, lfs

I'm trying to add `apt-get` package manager to LFS (LINUX FROM SCRATCH) system. I have found a solution explaining how to '[compile apt-get and dpkg](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/hints/downloads/files/OLD/apt.txt)' for LFS. But it's very old and unusable. I searched for `apt-get` source code and found it on [debian.org](https://packages.debian.org/squeeze/apt). It is Debian version of `apt`. I have downloaded `apt-0.8.10.3.deb` package and extracted its contents to the root directory of LFS. When my LFS system boots up and I type `apt-get`, this error is shown:

```
E: Unable to determine a suitable packaging system type.
```

1. How can I add `apt-get` to LFS and get it working?
2. What does the above error mean?

Answer (score 3):

1. Jimminy Cricket, that hint is **Old**:

> CHANGELOG:
> [2002-06-12]   * Initial hint.
> [2003-09-17]   * Changed format to fit new guidelines, added disclaimer
> about dpkg 1.10.

Can you reverse everything you did and try the [Use dpkg (.deb) package management on LFS 6.3.](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/hints/downloads/files/dpkg.txt), which is newer (but not by much):

> CHANGELOG:
> [2008-11-05]   * Initial hint.

2. I skimmed both hints, and it looks as if the version you linked didn't contain anything on the configuration files needed in the newer versions of `dpkg` and `apt`.  An example of which is [/etc/apt.conf](http://linux.die.net/man/5/apt.conf).

---

If that doesn't work, you could try the [RPM Hint](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/hints/downloads/files/rpm.txt) from our friends at Redhat. I've bookmarked both hints, and I'll try them in a Virtualbox VM, and report back here (This will take awhile).  In the meantime, have a look at [Gentoo](https://www.gentoo.org/get-started/about/), which is basically LFS + a package manager (portage)

---

### Update

I'm using a Fedora Core 22 Virtualbox VM to build LFS as another VM disk.  I'll provide more precise steps after the build completes.

Comment: I'll waited for your report @eyoung100!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed for me by :

```
echo "buster/sid" > /etc/debian_version
```

Comment: Could you say something about _why_ this fixed it for you and what other consequences doing this may have?

Comment: works for me. im using `echo unstable | sudo tee /etc/debian_version`. `apt-get` requires that file. the debian version has an effect on package versions. see also https://www.debian.org/releases/. another required file is [/etc/apt/sources.list](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList): `sudo mkdir /etc/apt; echo -e "deb http://deb.debian.org/debian unstable main\ndeb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian unstable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list; sudo apt-get update`